# select value from another table if record is found else, use the value on current table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm trying to get the values from another table2 if a match exist, else, select the value in table1 but it's taking a long time to execute the query.

```
select table1.field1, table1.field2, 
case 
    when exist (select top 1 
                from table2 
                where table2.field1=table1.field3
                and table2.field2 is not null 
                order by date desc) 
    then (select top 1
            from table2 
            where table2.field1=table1.field3 
            and table2.field2 is not null 
            order by date desc) 
    else table1.field3 
end 
from table1
```

any other way to re-write this query?

please help! n00b here :(

Comment: Which field want to fetch from `table2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use `outer apply`:

```
select t1.field1, t1.field2, coalesce(t2.??, t1.field3)
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.field1=  t1.field3 and t2.field2 is not null
      order by t2.date desc
     ) t2;
```

It is unclear what field you are talking about, because it is missing from the question; hence, the `??`.

Comment: thank you so much it ran definitely much faster! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, coalesce(t2.field2,t1.field3) as field3
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
on t2.field1=t1.field3  
and t2.date = (select max(date) from table2 t2e where t2.field1=t2e.field2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    table1.field1, 
    table1.field2, 
    COALESCE(table2.field2,table1.field3)
FROM
    table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    table2
ON
    table2.field1=table1.field3
```

- COALESCE skips all the null values in the list.
- LEFT OUTER JOIN returns all values from the first table, but puts null values where there is no corresponding row in the second table.